# Specify the inverse of the matrix $g_{ij}=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$, where $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, inverse

Let $V$ be an inner product space with a basis $(v_1,...,v_n)$.

I know that the Gram matrix
\begin{equation}
G=\begin{pmatrix}
\langle v_1,v_1\rangle&\cdots&\langle v_1,v_n\rangle\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
\langle v_n,v_1\rangle&\cdots&\langle v_n,v_n\rangle
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
g_{11}&\cdots&g_{1n}\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
g_{n1}&\cdots&g_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is invertible, but is it possible to explicitly specify the inverse (maybe involving the dual basis)?

**Motivation**: For those who have heard about the metric tensor: I'd like to have a formula for $g^{ij}$ (which boils down to the question above).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085301/inverse-of-a-gram-matrix

Comment: Construct the dual basis $\{u^1,...,u^n\}$. Then $$g^{i,j}=\langle u^i,u^j\rangle$$

Comment: @K.defaoite Thank you, I suspected that :)

Comment: @Physor Thank you, you are right that this is essentially the same question (it did not answer my question, but it was interesting to learn about the Gram Matrix, so thank you for sharing the link).

Comment: @Filippo You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we know that
\begin{align*}
    \phi\colon V&\to V^*\\
    v&\mapsto\langle v|\,\cdot\,\rangle
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism. We can construct an inner product on $V^*$ by defining
\begin{equation}
\langle\omega,\eta\rangle=\left\langle\phi\,^{-1}(\omega),\phi\,^{-1}(\eta)\right\rangle
\end{equation}
for $\omega,\eta\in V^{*}$.
With this definition, you can easily prove that
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
g^{11}&\cdots&g^{1n}\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
g^{n1}&\cdots&g^{nn}
\end{pmatrix}:=
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle v^1,v^1\rangle&\cdots&\langle v^1,v^n\rangle\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
\langle v^n,v^1\rangle&\cdots&\langle v^n,v^n\rangle
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is the inverse of $G$.

Comment: How are the vectors $v^i$ defined?

Comment: @gen Recall that $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is assumed to be a basis of $V$. $(v^1,\ldots,v^n)$ is the dual basis.

Comment: But then I am a little confused about what you are claiming. Isn't the preimage of $v^i$ under $\phi$ just $v_i$. In that case isn't $g^{ij} = \langle v^i, v^j \rangle = \langle v_i, v_j \rangle = g_{ij}$?

Comment: @gen "Isn't the preimage of $v^i$ under $\phi$ just $v_i$" - 1) To be precise, we can only consider the preimages of sets and the preimage of a set is another set. $\phi^{-1}(v^i)$ is the image of $v^i$ under the inverse of $\phi$. 2) Note that your claim is equivalent to $\phi(v_i)=v^i$. But this equality is not always correct:$$\phi (v_i)=\sum_{k=1}^n(\phi(v_i))(v_k)v^k=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle v_i,v_k\rangle v^k$$So you are right if the basis is orthonormal, i.e. if the Gram matrix equals the identity matrix.

Comment: @gen Since $v^1,\ldots,v^n$ is a basis of $V^*$, we even have the following equivalence:$$G=I\Leftrightarrow \forall i: \phi(v_i)=v^i$$

Answer (score 1):

If
$$
v_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}e_j
$$
with the $e_j$'s forming an orthonormal basis,
$$
\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} a_{jk}
$$
and hence
$$
U= \big(\langle v_i,v_j\rangle\big)_{i,j=1}^n=AA^T,
$$
where $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$.

So $U^{-1}=A^{-T}A^{-1}$.